# Need a list of rule of NewsLetter acceptable html elemts and attributes

Tags: html, css, newsletter

I am trying to find a list of acceptable html elements and attributes that work in most e-mail clients.
The only thing I know is these elements: table,span,img
but how about the acceptable attributes? I know that tables can use padding in the td but never ever use margin.
Any other rules ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of CSS attributes allowed in various email clients from Campaign Monitor.
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/